# BASH | If command equals something, else if do something

Tags: bash, if-statement, case

im trying to create a BASH script that will run constantly in the background. This bash script is supposed to ask for a result from the command rpi-cecd and if it contains 45:00, do something and if it contains 45:03, do something else. But at the moment, I can not get the script working if I ask for more than one result.

Working Code, but only asking for 45:00

```
/home/rpi-cecd/rpi-cecd | grep -q "45:00" && ok
```

Code I tried, but did not work at all.

```
/home/rpi-cecd/rpi-cecd | grep '45' > /dev/null
if [[ $? =~ .*45:00.* ]]
then
    echo "OK Button Clicked - HMS"
    ok
elif [ $? == *"45:03"* ]
then
    echo "Left Button Clicked - Canteen"
    left
else
    echo "Nothing Clicked?"
fi
```

**EDIT**
I just tried this with no luck.

```
hhmm=$(/home/rpi-cecd/rpi-cecd)
case "$hhmm" in
        45[:]00 )
                ok
                ;;
        45[:]03 )
                left
                ;;
        * )
                 echo "don't know how to process $hhmm"
                ;;
esac
```

Comment: As @Someprogrammerdude suggests and at least use the same square bracket strategy in if and elif (suggest to use doubled square brackets in both). Does it work?

Comment: One problem is that `$?` is the *exit code* of the last command (normally zero for success, a non-negative number for failure). It doesn't contain the result of the output. If you need the output from the `grep` command you need to capture it.

Comment: `$?` is the returns status of the most recently executed cmd. It is always an integer, it will not contain anything like `45:00`. Lots of other issues here But try your first cmd and save its output to a var, ile. `hhmm=$(rpi-cecd... )` . Now compare it whit `case "$hhmm" in 45[:]00 ) cmd1 ... ; 45[:]03 ) cmd2 ... ;; * ) echo "don't know how to process $hhmm" ;; esac`. Good luck.

Comment: Shellter, can you explain more how i should use this? When i pasted it in and changed cmd1 to an echo, the terminal does not give any response when running the code?

Comment: What is the normal output of  `rpi-cecd`

Comment: Usually something like: `cec_callback: debug: reason=0x0008, length=0x02, retval=0x00, initiator=0x0, follower=0x1, opcode=0x45, operand1=0x00, operand2=0x00 payload=[(01):45:00]` It works out the button i press from the last 4 numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `rpi-cecd` runs continuously without exiting, you can't just capture its output once. You need to continually read from it. You can do that by piping its output to a `while read` loop.

```
/home/rpi-cecd/rpi-cecd | while IFS= read -r line; do
    case $line in
        *45:00*)
            ok
            ;;
        *45:03*)
            left
            ;;
        *)
            echo "don't know how to process $line"
            ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: This still doesnt work :/ Forgot to mention, but this command is like a tail, it is always writing things to the terminal and when I click the OK button on the TV Remote, it writes a line of code containing 45:00. (If that changes anything)